# cy.getBy*** is not a function

Tags: e2e-testing, cypress

I'm trying to run Cypress during my Azure release pipeline. I install all the packages I install locally but when I run the Cypress tests I get several errors:

> TypeError: cy.visit(...).getByText is not a function
>
> TypeError: cy.getByLabelText is not a function
>
> TypeError: cy.getByPlaceholderText is not a function

I've added the following packages to my `package.json` devDependencies section:

```
"@testing-library/cypress": "^4.0.4",
"@testing-library/react": "^8.0.4",
"@testing-library/dom": "latest",
```

Any ideas why Cypress is returning these TypeErrors?

This is an example of a written test:

```
it("can request to join private team", () => {
  const privateTeamId = "fe1fa897-2e90-4ecb-91f9-0c9bb33ef63a";
  cy.get(`[id=${privateTeamId}]`)
    .click()
    .getByText("Request membership")
    .click()
    .getByText("Membership request sent");
});
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to extend Cypress' `cy` command.

Just add this `import '@testing-library/cypress/add-commands';` line to your project's `cypress/support/commands.js`

After adding this line, if it still doesn't work then close Cypress and start it again.

**Note: outdated answer from 2020 (cypress moves quickly) as `getBy`s are now replaced by using `findBy`s**

Answer (score 7):

### getBy has been deprecated and removed

The `getBy*` queries does not exist in the integration between Testing Library + Cypress.

So I just changed from `cy.getByText` to `cy.findByText` and everything worked.

According to the docs:

> Note: the get* queries are not supported because for reasonable Cypress tests you need retryability and find* queries already support that. query* queries are no longer necessary since v5 and will be removed in v6. find* fully support built-in Cypress assertions (removes the only use-case for query*).

https://testing-library.com/docs/cypress-testing-library/intro